# How to print DF without back slash in R?

Tags: r

I've this code:

```
a = "A\"a"
b = "B\"b"
c = "C\"c"

df = data.frame(a,b,c)
```

When I try to print some column

```
df$a
```

I get: `"A\"a"`

How can I hide the black slash and to get just: `A"a`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I am getting `A"a`

Comment: @VvdL Then you must have done something different. If you just do what OP did, you will reproduce OP's observed behaviour.

Comment: `a = "A\"a"
b = "B\"b"
c = "C\"c"
df = data.frame(a,b,c)
df$a
#> [1] A"a
#> Levels: A"a`

Comment: @VvdL In that case you are running a quite outdated version of R. Current versions no longer convert strings to factors when constructing data.frames. The "Levels: A"a" output should have tipped you off that something was different here.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want isn’t just to hide the backslash; you want to print the *contents* of the string, whereas R at the moment prints the *representation* of the string using R syntax — that is: with quotes and escape sequences.

This is the default behaviour of the `print` function, which gets called implicitly on all values that get printed on the terminal. To avoid it, you need to use one of the functions to explicitly output a value *instead of using `print` or auto-printing*:

- `cat(df$a, '\n')`
- `message(df$a)` (writes to the standard error stream)
- `writeLines(df$a, stdout())`
- …

This is a *general* behaviour of R, incidentally, it is unrelated to data.frames (the data you are printing is a regular vector, not a data.frame).

Comment: TY, but what if I don't want to print and I want to use the vector in my Shiny app?

Comment: @asdf1212 Use `renderText` instead of `renderPrint`.

Comment: I'm trying to make <select> in HTML and to put inside my string like: "<option>", MYSTRING,"</option>". It's working well except the back slash

Comment: @asdf1212 *How* are you making the `<select>` element? If you use `selectInput` or `selectizeInput`, this will work as expected. In general, you need to be *much more specific* when asking questions, to avoid sending people on a wild goose chase: this has now very little to do with your original question (although my answer still explains relevant fundamentals of R semantics).

Comment: I use HTML() function

Comment: @asdf1212 Don't do that. :-) Use `selectInput` instead. But at any rate the `HTML` function also outputs the right thing, so it is still not entirely clear what you are *exactly* doing.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid it.. It makes me a lot of issues..